# Dll build in IDEs

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ide

Is there any way to find out with which **IDE or Tool** the **.Net DLL assembly** was build?

I have looked the DLL through **CFF Explorer** and have not found any information about that in the DLL.

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: @Natrium the main question is not specifically with which version of the Visual Studio but with which IDE or tool was dll built as every tool has its changes, settings and flags for dll. I have updated my question.

Comment: A mental model that an IDE or build tool would leave a fingerprint behind in a .NET assembly is just not accurate.  Pretty obvious when you look at the properties of a C# project, very little to choose from.  As compared to a C++ projects, many dozens of settings.  A .NET assembly is just data with no facility to *intentionally* leave any build artifacts visible.

Comment: @HansPassant If I understood you correctly it's pretty difficult to say either the .Net Assembly was compiled by Visual Studio or by Mono?

Comment: have you ever used `PEiD` ?

Comment: @Nofuzy no, I have not. But I will take a look on it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PEiD` instead, it will show the compiler.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/PEiD-updated.shtml

or you can use `ExEinfo PE`